# Get blank page from chrome and 403 error from IE After successful SharePoint 2010 install on Windows 7 

Tags: windows-7, 403

follow the Microsoft [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx) 
, i install SharePoint 2010 on my windows 7 Ultimate 64x.

But after successful install and configuration, when i try to browse central administration with chrome, i get a prompt for user, when i ok this prompt, i see a blank page.

If i use IE, I see 403 error.

I search in web and there a some suggestion, but problem not solved, yet.

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a hard work, I find it!

IIS

My IIS is the problem. I uninstall it and install again and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the various SharePoint services have started correctly? Especially SQL Server.